# Is it posible to turn android status bar fully transparent with Xamarin Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, statusbar, transparent

I'm looking for a way to turn Android StatusBar completely transparent with Xamarin Forms. I can easily make it semitransparent by setting `android:windowTranslucentStatus` to `true` . It will be black with an opacity of about 50% but anyway its background will be visible, which is not what I want.
I found this article, and this is exactly what I need as a result
https://learnpainless.com/android/material/make-fully-android-transparent-status-bar
but the problem is that there seems to be no obvious way to achieve the same in Xamarin Forms. I just haven't found a way to set decor flags like that nor a way to do this in styles.xml
[image]

I've also seen this topic (which was suggested to me while I was creating mine) [Android transparent status bar and actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907615/android-transparent-status-bar-and-actionbarm) and googled this one [Xamarin Forms background image with transparent status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44241472/xamarin-forms-background-image-with-transparent-status-bar) and several others.
But all those solutions end up with a semitransparent status bar as well.
So I'm completely stuck with this

Comment: Still no solution to this? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Nope. I decided to forget about xamarin and completely switched to Flutter

Answer (score 1):

I've just found an easy solution. 
I just need to set a colorPrimaryDark with alpha component. I was setting alpha component at the end of a hex value (like on android) but I needed to set it at the begining in xamarin.
So the solution is like this:

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/statusTransparent</item>
```

And the color itself (in colors.xml) is

```
<color name="statusTransparent">#26ff9b76</color>
```

Where 26 is the HEX alpha component. Which means 15% alpha, but if I change it to 00 I get fully transparent status bar
I got the values here [Hex transparency in colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852122/hex-transparency-in-colors)

---

### LATER

Well, it's not a completely working solution. Even though the status bar turns transparent, xamarin doesn't draw its pages under this status bar, only the activity's background is visible
 [image]

The only way to make xamarin draw its contents under the status bar is to make it semitransparent via `android:windowTranslucentStatus`
But in this case it looks like this:
[image]

And it's not what I want. So the question is still open

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the OnCreate method of MainActivity.cs

This will remove the status bar from all screens.

```
// On Create in the activity
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);
    this.Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.YourLayout);
}
```

if you want for both platforms, I would prefer you do it in the code behind file :

```
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage  
{  
      public MyPage()  
      {  
         InitializeComponent();  
         NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);  
      }
}
```

Comment: I don't need a fullsreen application, I only need the status bar to be transparent but its icons and clock must be visible all the time